# Optimización de datos en un dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview

Tengo un DGV en visual studio el cual obtiene sus datos de una base de datos, el problema es que este me ralentiza bastante la aplicación debido a que es una tabla de clientes (1500 aprox), así mismo tengo una función dentro del dgv que me permite buscar datos el cual tarda bastante en cargar. ¿Qué puedo hacer para optimizar el rendimiento del dgv?

Dejo el código del método de búsqueda que tengo aplicado en el dgv:

```
if (tbnomclien.Text != "")
        {
            dataGrid.CurrentCell = null;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows)
            {
                r.Visible = false;
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
                {
                    if ((c.Value.ToString().ToUpper()).IndexOf(tbnomclien.Text.ToUpper()) == 0)
                    {
                        r.Visible = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }                                                                                                                                                               
            }

        }
        else
        {
            conexion.cargar_clientes(dataGrid);
        }
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar una vista en vez de una consulta limpia, por lo que así cargando los datos en datatables te será mas optimo de trabajar que con la conexión directa por visual

Comment: Tu data grid contiene una propiedad source, ese source es lo que debes filtrar para obtener un numero menor de elementos una vez que filtras tu nueva fuente es ese datasourceFiltrado, asi seran mas eficientes tus busquedas. ahora para filtrar investiga como funciona dataGrid.DefaultView.RowFilter.  // row filter es un query asi que sera facil implementar un select * like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo en ese caso haría todo lo que haces en dos bloques foreach consecutivos, en uno solo, pues ten en cuenta que si tienes 1500 filas y haces dos recorridos por ellas, es recorrer 3000 filas, es mucho más tiempo de procesamiento consumido; yo haría lo siguiente:

```
    if (tbnomclien.Text != "")
     {
         dataGrid.CurrentCell = null;
     foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows)
          {
      //Declarar una variable booleana para capturar la propiedad visible
      //La pongo en false, de manera predeterminada
      //De esta forma solo se colocará true a la propiedad visible, cuando se cumpla la condición
      bool visbl = false;
             foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
                    {
                       if ((c.Value.ToString().ToUpper()).IndexOf(tbnomclien.Text.ToUpper()) == 0)
                        {
                            visbl  = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                    r.Visible = visbl;                                                                                                                                          
                }

            }
            else
            {
                conexion.cargar_clientes(dataGrid);
            }
```

tal ves puedas implementar otras cosas adicionales, para mejorar el rendimiento, pero lo primero es optimizar tu código, y comienza por no repetir un bloque recorriendo los mismos elementos dos veces consecutivas, solo para cambiar la propiedad visible.

Comment: @Yahirmuñoz Gracias por aceptar mi respuesta, como la mejor, es un estimulo para mi pues soy nuevo en el sitio y además, desarrollador autodidacta. Solo agregar que si lo crees justo, me gustaría que puntearas mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo dos formas de realizarlo, 1500 registros no es mucho aunque lo parezca (depende de que info cargue).

1- El metodo lo haces con una Task y se ejecuta en segundo plano mientras la pantalla no se bloquea.
2- En la consulta que tengas mas carga de trabajo puedes usar Parallel, esta función es para que la libreria determine si es necesario hacer un trabajo en parallelo y la ejecuta.

> foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows.AsParallel())

```
if (tbnomclien.Text != "")
    {
        dataGrid.CurrentCell = null;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            r.Visible = false;
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGrid.Rows.AsParallel())
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
            {
                if ((c.Value.ToString().ToUpper()).IndexOf(tbnomclien.Text.ToUpper()) == 0)
                {
                    r.Visible = true;
                    break;

                }
            }                                                                                                                                                               
        }

    }
    else
    {
      await Task.Run(()=> conexion.cargar_clientes(dataGrid));
    }
```

//Colocale a tu metodo la palabra async

Comment: Utilice el código tal cual y primero me tiro éste error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' y posteriormente al volver a ejecutar buscaba una vez y posteriormente se quedaban esos resultados sin mostrar otros a pesar de modificar el texto del textbox.

Comment: sobre que Linea? no tengo todo tu codigo, sino lo pruebo yo

Comment: En la configuracion de Excepciones, marca la casilla System.NullReferenceException, para saber exactamente donde lanza el error.

Comment: el error me lo marcaba exactamente donde termina el código, en la llave "}"

Comment: debugea que no llegue null el campo dataGrid que es lo que estas pasando a tu metodo como parametro.